Is it possible to concatenate two ranges in Kotlin?
I would like to do something like
for (i in 1..8,20..25)

or
for (i in 1..8 + 20..25)

Is it or something similar allowing to iterate over or check that an element is in a concatenated range possible in Kotlin?

for (i in (1..8) + (20..25))

Perhaps something like this?
for (i in (1..8) + (20..25)) {
    println(i)
}

prints:
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
20
21
22
23
24
25
You can try it here: https://pl.kotl.in/-0kdY_y5U?theme=darcula

Works fine, thank you.
Not sure why parentheses are needed by language design though.

@AlexanderItes + has higher precedence than .., so without parentheses it is 1..28..25 which is a syntax error. See: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/grammar.html#expressions

Please note it replaces a range with a list. It has to materialize all items in the memory. It is probably not a problem if ranges are small as in the example above, but something like for (x in (0..999) + (1000..1999)) doesn't look good to me. AFAIK, Kotlin stdlib doesn't provide support for "multiranges", so we would have to implement it ourselves. Alternatively, we can use sequences: for (x in (0..999).asSequence() + (1000..1999).asSequence()).
